# How to discard records containg offer_price greater than original price

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

the csv file contains many attributes. i have to remove the offer_price which is greater than the original price.
price columns contain the following row-wise. following are the five rows. how to do it in python

{'offer_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 25.0}, 'regular_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 25.0}}
{'offer_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 20.0}, 'regular_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 20.0}}
{'offer_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 18.0}, 'regular_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 18.0}}
{'offer_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 30.0}, 'regular_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 30.0}}
{'offer_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 35.0}, 'regular_price': {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 35.0}}

Name: price, dtype: int64

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filtering values by keys of dicts, `.get` is more general - working also if some key missing:

```
mask = (df['price'].map(lambda x: x.get('offer_price').get('value') < 
                                  x.get('regular_price').get('value')))
```

Or if always each keys in dict exist is possible use:

```
mask = df['price'].map(lambda x: x['offer_price']['value'] < x['regular_price']['value'])
```

---

```
df1 = df[mask]
```

Comment: I got error as AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: By applying second suggestion 
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @KalyanMohanty - Use `import ast` and `df['price'] = df['price'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my solution for convert strings to dictionaries